# Indexeddb AbortError

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Below is my Javascript code for opening an indexedDB. I have tested the code several times successfully in Firefox 21 before, but now I am seeing an AbortError being returned by the indexedDB.open() function in e.target.error.name.

```
var openDB = function(dbCallBack) {
  var openDB = function(dbCallBack) {
    window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB; 
    window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
    window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;

    request = window.indexedDB.open('mgDB');
    request.onerror = function(e) {
      alert('Error: ' + e.target.error.name + ': Failed to open the database');
      dbCallBack(false, false);
    };

    request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
      dbCallBack(true, false);
    };

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
      db = e.target.result;
      if (db.objectStoreNames.length == 0) { 
        dbCallBack(true, true);
      } else {
        dbCallBack(true, false);
      }
    };
  };
};
```

Here's how the openDB() function is being called. The code for dbCallBack function is inline below:

```
if (!db) {
    var dbOpenSuccess;
    openDB(function(dbOpenSuccess, emptyTableMsg) {
      if (emptyTableMsg) {
        displayEmptyTableMsg();
      } else if (dbOpenSuccess) {
        displayTableContents();         
      }
    }); 
}
```

Note: I have tried clearing the browser cache and deleting the indexedDB manually from the folder C:\users{userID}\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles before re-running the tests. I ran the same code successfully at http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDB. What could be wrong?

Comment: can you show what you are doing in the doCallBack function?

Comment: I have edited the question above to answer your question.

Comment: ALso, please note that the dbCallBack function has worked successfully before.

Comment: I think youbwill have to provide more code. Probably some thing goes wrong in the displayTableContens method. An abort error will happen on the transaction. Are you using "readonly" or "readwrite" as transaction mode to open a transaction or do you use the deprecated int values?

Answer (score 0):

if you listen onabort event, your code will be fine, as follow.

```
request.onsuccess = function(e) {
  db = e.target.result;
  db.onabort = function(e) {
    db.close();
    db = null;
  }
  if (db.objectStoreNames.length == 0) { 
    dbCallBack(true, true);
  } else {
    dbCallBack(true, false);
  }
};
```

Comment: That didn't work. The problem is that request.onsuccess event is not triggered at all. I inserted db.close() in the code for request.onerror event, but that did not work either because e.target.result does not contain the database.

Comment: Then, it is likely that AbortError come from unhandled event from an onerror handler of some request. These error likely to come from onupgradeneeded callback. Make sure you don't have any error there.

Comment: You were right about the callback from the onupgradeneeded event. I was not initializing the db variable when the callback function was called onupgradeneeded, and that caused the onerror event to fired. After commenting out dbcallback from onupgradeneeded, I was able to make the code work. Thanks for your help.